# Mis Labels se borran en WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Tengo una ventana principal con algunos labels, y tengo algunos botones que abren una ventana secundaria (es la misma para todos los botones) pero dependiendo del boton que presione es el contenido de los labels de esta segunda ventana. 
En la segunda ventana tengo dos textbox, que van a llenar su contenido en algun label de la ventana principal, todo esto depende del contenido del label.

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    MainWindow main;
    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        main = new MainWindow();

        switch (tirA.Content)
        {
            case "1":
                switch (tirB.Content)
                {
                    case "2":
                        main.c1v2.Content = textTirA.Text;
                        main.c2v1.Content = textTirB.Text;
                        break;

                    case "3":
                        main.c1v3.Content = textTirA.Text;
                        main.c3v1.Content = textTirB.Text;
                        break;
                }
                break;
        }

        main.Show();
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

Mi problema es que al volver a llamar a la funcion *Button_Click* y querer llenar otro label, lo que ya habia llenado antes se borra. No sé si me explique bien, pero espero que entiendan y me ayudan a solucionarlo.

Comment: Honestamente no entiendo bien tu explicación, la parte de "al volver a llamar a la funcion Button_Click y querer llenar otro label, lo que ya habia llenado antes se borra" es lo que no entiendo, qué otro label quieres llenar? y cuál es el que se borra? te fijaste que la ventana que estás abriendo es una totalmente nueva y no una previa? Por favor se más específico y detallado. Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

se borra por que dentro del evento click tu creas una nueva instancia nueva de MainWindow() si tu quiere que se conserve el texto anterior deberías tener en tu code behind una variable como almacen y pasarla en todo momento

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    MainWindow main;
    string storeA = "";
    string storeB = "";

    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        main = new MainWindow();

        switch (tirA.Content)
        {
            case "1":
                switch (tirB.Content)
                {
                    case "2":           
            storeA = string.IsNullOrEmpty(storeA) ? textTirA.Text : storeA + textTirA.Text;
                        main.c1v2.Content = storeA;
            storeB = string.IsNullOrEmpty(storeB) ? textTirB.Text : storeB + textTirB.Text;
                        main.c2v1.Content = storeB;
                        break;
                    case "3":
            storeA = string.IsNullOrEmpty(storeA) ? textTirA.Text : storeA + textTirA.Text;
                        main.c1v3.Content = storeA;
            storeB = string.IsNullOrEmpty(storeB) ? textTirB.Text : storeB + textTirB.Text;
                        main.c3v1.Content = storeB;
                        break;
                }
                break;
        }

        main.Show();
        this.Close();
    }
}
```